# how to print parsing errors in a textfile while parsing with XERCES

Tags: java

When I parse xml files with XERCES parser, the error statements were printed in the command window itself. I want it to be printed in a separate file to refer the errors in xml. Can anyone help me to do it.

Comment: Would you like to provide some additional info. For ex. chunk of code. I suppouse it is an uncathced exception that should be handled in right way.

Comment: I actually downloaded xerces and executed it using a batch file with the following content. Still I didn't tried with Java coding. I need a help to do it. <br/> @ECHO off set classpath=.;xercesImpl.jar;xercesSamples.jar;xml-apis.jar;resolver.jar;serializer.jar @ECHO on java sax.Counter -n -v -s -f %1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try redirecting the standard error stream to a text file. You can either do that at the command prompt ( not sure how under windows but google will probably know ), or you can do it in code by setting System.out to write to an a known file

`System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("system_err.txt")));`

( This assumes xerces is using stderr  - it may use stdout, in which case you'll just need to redirect that )